# Ruby PHP Server

Tags: php, ruby, session, session-variables, tcpserver

This is a basic version of the server I have made:

```
    require 'socket'

    server = TCPServer.new("localhost", 80)
    loop {
        Thread.new(server.accept) do |session|
            request = session.gets
            session.puts `php C:\server\root\index.php`
            session.close
        end
    }
```

PHP works with this but the thing is the sessions don't work and the "require()" and "include()" don't work. I've tried using the php.ini files from working servers but it does not make a difference.
So does anyone know how to fix the require, include functions and the sessions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why? O.o And for what?

Comment: Why does that matter?